# Flash Message Lost in Devise redirect to Wicked Wizard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, wicked-gem

This is likely a debugging problem more than anything else, but I'm losing a flash message between Devise's `after_sign_up_path_for` and the beginning of a Wicked wizard. I've tried multiple placements of `flash.keep` to no avail.

Is there any way to print the exact redirections that are happening so I can figure out where the message is being lost?

Here's the redirect code in my registrations controller:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
  logger.debug "entering redirect, flashing"
  flash[:analytics] = "signed_up"
  after_signup_index_path
end
```

Devise's `create` method contains a `redirect_to` call and I'm calling `super` above so I can't use `redirect_to after_signup_index_path` in the above block - might this solve the problem?

Here's the (condensed) Wicked wizard action:

```
def show
  flash.keep
  @user = current_user
  render_wizard
end
```

Comment: Can you give use some logs?

Comment: Also instead of overriding `after_sign_up_path_for` you can pass a block to super. `super { flash[:analytics] = "signed_up" }`. Almost all the Devise controllers/actions yield so you can use this to shoehorn your own code into the flow.